# Mat to Bitmap exception thrown

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, mat

The following are My Code for drawing border in openCV

```
Mat src = new Mat(imageChosen.getWidth(), imageChosen.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
Utils.bitmapToMat(imageChosen, src);
Mat dst = new Mat(imageChosen.getWidth(), imageChosen.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
Core.copyMakeBorder(src, dst, 10, 10, 10, 10, Core.BORDER_CONSTANT, new Scalar(0,0,0));
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageChosen.getWidth()+20, imageChosen.getHeight()+20,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(src, b);
```

and i don't know why it throw

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols) in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean), file /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp, line 97
E/org.opencv.android.Utils: nMatToBitmap catched cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
```

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#Mat(int,%20int,%20int,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar)) of `Mat`, you can see that the constructor expects its params in the following order: rows, columns.

You're passing the width (columns) first and the height (rows) after.

Instead of the following:

```
Mat src = new Mat(imageChosen.getWidth(), imageChosen.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

You should pass the height first:

```
Mat src = new Mat(imageChosen.getHeight(), imageChosen.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

For both `src` and `dst`.